# Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` in recent versions of React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to upgrade an old React Native app version (v.55) to the latest (v.61). I started this process by running `react-native init [project name]`. I then copied only my JavaScript files into the new project. I then try to build, it tells me I am missing a module, I install the module, repeat.

However there is one issue that I can not seem to solve:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `../javascript_shared/HomeScreen.js`: @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault could not be found within the project.
```

I am running

- react: 16.9.0
- react-native: 0.61.5
- @babel/core: 7.7.4
- @babel/runtime: 7.7.4

I have searched and searched, all coming up with the same answer: Downgrade `@babel/runtime` to version `7.0.0-beta.55` due to some change being made after that version. This, however, changes nothing (not to mention I would prefer not to revert to such an old version). I have cleared every cache and whatnot but still the same issue remains.

If I look in `node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers` I do see a `interopRequireDefault.js`.

There seem to be no forum posts of people having this issue with these recent versions anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I (sort of) figured it out.

I had a folder with JavaScript in it one level up (`../javascript_shared/`) and something in the build process did not like that. I had `watchFolders` in `metro.config.js` but apparently that was not enough.

I just moved this folder into the project root (where my `package.json` and `index.js` are).

Although this is not a proper solution I hope this helps someone. Maybe it will give that person the next place to look.